# Can I deform a solid cylinder to a standard one?

Tags: geometric-topology, low-dimensional-topology

Let $D^2$ be the closed unit disc in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and denote by $A\subseteq D^2$ the closed disc with radius $1/2$.

Suppose $F:D^2\times [0,1] \to D^2\times [0,1]$ is an embedding (homeomorphism onto its image) such that:

- $F$ is height preserving, that is $F(D^2\times\{t\}) \subseteq D^2\times\{t\}$ for every $t\in [0,1]$;
- the image of $F$ does not intersect the lateral surface $\partial D^2 \times [0,1]$;
- $F(D^2\times \{0\}) = A\times\{0\}$;
- $F(D^2\times \{1\}) = A\times\{1\}$.

Is it true that there exists a height preserving homeomorphism $H:D^2\times [0,1]\to D^2\times [0,1]$, extending the identity of the boundary, such that the image of the composition $H\circ F$ is $A\times [0,1]$?

Comment: It looks to me like the cylinder is not as important as the map that takes $D^2$ to $A$.  Try it there then see what you need to change when you take these spaces $\times I$.

Comment: Consider $D^2$ with an embedded disc $X$. Drawing two segments joining the boundary of $D^2$ with the boundary of $X$ one obtains three regions $X$,$Y$,$Z$, each homeomorphic to a disc. Repeat the same procedure with $A\subseteq D^2$, obtaining regions $A$,$B$,$C$. Now find three homeomorphisms $X\cong A, Y\cong B, Z\cong C$ agreeing on the boundaries. Together they should give the desired homeomorphism.

Comment: The problem is that if you slightly perturb the embedded circle the resulting homeomorphism could change a lot, so it seems difficult to adapt the construction to make it work for the cylinder.

Comment: Essentially what one needs is that the space of embeddings $D^2 \hookrightarrow D^2$ is simply connected with respect to the compact open topology. I believe this is true, but I'm not sure how to prove it nor do I know a reference.

Comment: Actually I think that the fundamental group $G$ of the space of embeddings $D^2\to D^2$ should be infinite cyclic. Counting how many times the embedded disc turns around its center you can define a surjective homomorphism from $G$ to $\mathbb{Z}$, and I believe this is an isomorphism.